# Replace degree sign and other on python

Tags: string, python-2.7, replace, special-characters

I need to "clean" these strings: - (S) 19º 52' 11,528", 19° 52' 11,528".

I just need the numbers, how can I do it in Python?

Cheers,

Comment: show the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you have to escape either quote (simple or double).

Then use `re.split()` on non-numbers, and wrap it in a list comprehension to remove the empty strings that `re.split` can generate at the end and convert to integer:

```
>>> import re
>>> z = '- (S) 19º 52\' 11,528", 19° 52\' 11,528"'
>>> [int(x) for x in re.split("\D+",z) if x]
[19, 52, 11, 528, 19, 52, 11, 528]
```

Note that it's ok for your usage, but won't work properly for negative numbers (the `-` sign would be stripped out)

To properly handle floats, that's a little more complex but still can be done as long as you don't have negative numbers:

```
>>> [float(x.replace(",",".")) for x in re.split("[^\d,]+",z) if x and x!=","]
[19.0, 52.0, 11.528, 19.0, 52.0, 11.528]
```

Comment: good remark, but such long/lat formats are fixed IIRC, so you always get the same number of fields not matter what. . could always exclude `","` from the split. But that brings us on the ground of "int or float from string". however, edited for completeness.